# Final vectors in Histogram of oriented gradient

Tags: opencv, histogram, gradient

The dimension of the image is 64 x 128. That is 8192 magnitude and gradient values. After the binning stage, we are left with 1152 values as we converted 64 pixels into 9 bins based on their orientation. Can you please explain to me how after L2 normalization we get 3780 vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: You have the gradients of the 64 x 128 patch.

**Calculate Histogram of Gradients in 8x8 cells**

This is where it starts to get interesting. The image is divided into 8x8 cells and a HOG is calculated for each 8x8 cells. One of the reasons why we use 8x8 cells is that it provides a compact representation. An 8x8 image patch contains 8x8x3 = 192 pixel values (color image). The gradient of this patch contains 2 values (magnitude and direction) per pixel which adds up to 8x8x2 = 128 values. These 128 numbers are represented using a 9-bin histogram which can be stored as an array of 9 numbers. This makes it more compact and calculating histograms over a patch makes this representation more robust to noise.

The histogram is essentially a vector of 9 bins corresponding to angles 0, 20, 40, 60 ... 180 corresponding to unsigned gradients.

**16 x 16 Block Normalization**

After creating the histogram based on the gradient of the image, we want our descriptor to be independent of lighting variations. Hence, we normalize the histogram. The vector norm for a RGB color [128, 64, 32] is sqrt(128*128 + 64*64 + 32*32) = 146.64, which is the infamous **L2-norm**. Dividing each element of this vector by 146.64 gives us a normalized vector [0.87, 0.43, 0.22]. If we were to multiply each element of this vector by 2, the normalized vector will remain the same as before.

Although simply normalizing the 9x1 histogram is intriguing, normalizing a bigger sized block of 16 x 16 is better. A 16 x 16 block has 4 histograms, which can be concatenated to form a 36 x 1 element vector and it can be normalized the same way as the 3 x 1 vector in the example. The window is then moved by 8 pixels and a normalized 36 x 1 vector is calculated over this window and the process is repeated (see the animation: [Courtesy](https://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/))

[image: Windowing]

**Calculate the HOG feature vector**

*This is where your question comes in.*

To calculate the final feature vector for the entire image patch, the 36 x 1 vectors are concatenated into on giant vector. Let us calculate the size:

1. How many positions of the 16 x 16 blocks do we have? There are 7 horizontal and 15 vertical positions, which gives - 105 positions.
2. Each 16 x 16 block is represented by a 36 x 1 vector. So when we concatenate them all into one giant vector we obtain a **36 x 105 = 3780 dimensional vector**.

For more details, look at [the tutorial where I learned.](https://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: it should be 192 pixel values in the first para. Care to edit?

Comment: Okay, now I have 3780 vectors with me. How can I draw something as shown on learnopencv.com( the gradients around Usain Bolt)? Basically, I want to create a bounding box across my subject. I am struggling with the visualization part.